# How to get new password by mail instead of password reset url (Forgot password)

Tags: 7, emails, tokens, users

When we click on "Forgot your password" and enter email id, Drupal will send password reset URL by mail.

**But is it possible Drupal send any random password by email instead of URL?**

I have checked [Registration Password Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/rpt) but this will helpful for new user registration only.

Is there any module available?

Comment: It is possible. Also, because such password will be accessible for email server admins etc, it very well might be illegal as possibly compromising customer's data. In Poland it is officially discouraged by GIODO ( Inspector General for the Protection of Personal Data) and thus makes site operator responsible for any password misuse, and all rules about people responsible for what they do - void. Rationale: if you send a link, the attack window is short. If you send password, any admin (or anyone who hacked mailserver) can access it at any time...

Comment: Actually I am developing iOS app(Drupal Services module), where if someone enter his/her email id in "Forgot password"  text box, he/she should receive password by email instead of redirecting him/her on website

Comment: @FirozSabaliya - What did you end up using?

Comment: I have used Recovery password module. https://www.drupal.org/project/recovery_pass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Recovery Password](https://www.drupal.org/project/recovery_pass) (Email New Password) module.

> Recovery Password module makes it possible for Drupal to send any
>   random generated password(new password) by email instead of URL to the
>   user.

Refer to the module page for detailed description. Feel free to contact me, in case of any issue. I'm maintainer of this module.